# linux command to check POSIX message queue

Tags: linux, posix, ipc

We can check the details of system V message queue with the help of `ipcs`command. Is there any command to check POSIX message queue in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no command I know of but there exists a libc function call which can get the statistics:

**man 3 mq_getattr**

```
   mq_getattr() returns an mq_attr structure  in  the  buffer  pointed  by
   attr.  This structure is defined as:

       struct mq_attr {
           long mq_flags;       /* Flags: 0 or O_NONBLOCK */
           long mq_maxmsg;      /* Max. # of messages on queue */
           long mq_msgsize;     /* Max. message size (bytes) */
           long mq_curmsgs;     /* # of messages currently in queue */
       };
```

Answer (score 15):

If you're lucky enough to use *HP-UX*, the command [`pipcs` (PDF)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02261697/c02261697.pdf) (*sorry link broken, no current archive*, see [this](https://www.unix.com/man-page/hpux/1/pipcs/) man page on unix.com instead) performs the POSIX equivalent to the SysV IPC `ipcs` command. Sadly, it has never appeared for other OS's. The current (January 2021) [util-linux](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/) package which provides `ipcs` barely mentions POSIX mqueues.

If you have `mqueue` mounted on `/dev/mqueue`, what *is* supported is reading metadata for an existing queue as a file:

```
user@linux $ sudo mount -t mqueue mqueue /dev/mqueue
user@linux $ mq_create -c /myQ
user@linux $ cat /dev/mqueue/myQ
QSIZE:0          NOTIFY:0     SIGNO:0     NOTIFY_PID:0
```

The `QSIZE` is sadly only the size in bytes, not messages; on Linux there is (as yet, kernel 5.4) no message count field – unlike *FreeBSD* which provides a `CURMSG` value:

```
user@freebsd $ cat /mnt/mqueue/myQ
QSIZE:0          MAXMSG:32         CURMSG:0          MSGSIZE:1024
```

So the answer *should* be "mount the mqueue FS and use `cat`", but it's not :(

(Mounting the mqueue FS is not a prerequisite for using the MQ API, it just lets you do some "everything is a file" stuff.)

There is good coverage of message queues in the book [*The Linux Programming Interface*](http://nostarch.com/tlpi), including C source code for various CLI tools to create, inspect and use message queues. Happily chapter 52 of the book which covers this topic is currently available free to download. See `pmsg_getattr.c`.

The canonical reference code from Stephen's *Unix Network Programming (Vol 2) 2nd Ed.* (1999) is available [here](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv22e/unpv22e.html), it provides amongst other things `mqgetattr` which will do the job too  (though you'll likely need to massage a couple of lines in the top level `config.h`, the `#define`'s for various `uint` types conflict with contemporary Unix system headers).

There are also [Ruby](http://bogomips.org/ruby_posix_mq/), [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eiljatabac/POSIX-RT-MQ-0.03/MQ.pm) and [TCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl-mq/?source=navbar) modules for this, the Ruby one comes with a [`posix-mq-rb`](http://bogomips.org/ruby_posix_mq/posix-mq-rb_1.html) CLI tool.

Comment: I using ubuntu system..

Answer (score 12):

`$ ipcs -q` will provide message queue stats from the command line.

`$ ipcs -m` will provide shared memory stats from the command line.

`$ ipcs` will provide all ipc mechanism stats.

Comment: `ipcs` is not for POSIX1 message queues

Comment: `ipcs` is used for System V message queues and not for POSIX message queues